# Python 2.6 complains about missing a math module - I cannot use it after some (other) software update. Any tips?

Tags: python, macos, installation

I am relatively new with Python. Here is my problem:

My environment was python2.6 with MacOs 10.6.8. I recently had to update my system with Python2.7 and some other stuff (Eclipse 3.6 and GoogleAppEngine). Python works fine within Eclipse, however, I want to keep the shell-mode in being able to quickly test small stuff on the commandline. I am getting this error message, and I need this to get rid of asap:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> import urllib2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py",
line 92, in <module>
import httplib
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", 
line 77, in <module>
import mimetools
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/mimetools.py", 
line 6, in <module>
import tempfile
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", 
line 34, in <module>
from random import Random as _Random
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/random.py", 
line 45, in <module>
from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6    
/lib-dynload/math.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyLong_AsScaledDouble
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/lib-dynload/math.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/math.so
```

Anyway, this was the python version that my macbook was shipped with at buying time. I don't think i want to waste time on removing, re-stalling etc. an apple-approved python version. Does anybody know how I can get my system back to run properly? And why does this error occur at all? Thanks for quick help!

Comment: From the directory names, I guess there are things from the older version 2.6 interfering with the newest. It might have something to do with the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Try doing this: `import sys` then `print sys.path`. Most probably you'll see 2.6 everywhere.

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` and make sure its got the correct paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your new python within a virtualenv, so that it is isolated from the system install.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv